# How can I get a webpage to click on a button upon loading? Tried this and doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, elementor

Would appreciate your help with this.
I'm trying to get the site to automatically click on a button, when the site is loading.

The button I'm referring to is the blue one, above the fold right when you enter the page,
the text is "Full 2022-2023 Schedule".

Site is running Elementor on Wordpress.

Any ideas?

I tried adding this script to the homepage of the site [www.thenflschedule.com](http://www.thenflschedule.com),
but it just doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("button").click();
</script>
```

Update:
There's a script on the page to open popups only when the window or any element is clicked. I thought that by auto-clicking a button, it would trigger the popup, but it doesn't. I would still need to click manually anywhere on the page for the pop up to open.

Is there a function to click anywhere on the window, that would trigger the popup script?

This is the pop up script that's running on the page:
`<script data-cfasync="false" src="//acacdn.com/script/suv4.js" data-adel="lwsu" cdnd="acacdn.com" zid="323555"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

The button doesn't have an ID called "button". You can only use `.getElementById` when the element you are trying to access has an `id` parameter.
Try using

```js
let x = document.getElementsByClassName("elementor-button-link elementor-button elementor-size-sm");
x[0].click();
```

That button (actually its a link tag) has the above classes thats why I have used `.getElementsByClassName` instead of `.getElementById`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Viraj,
looks like it's working now,
but it doesn't do what I thought it would.

There's a script on the page to open popups only when the window or any element is clicked. I thought that by auto-clicking a button, it would trigger the popup, but it doesn't. I would still need to click manually anywhere on the page for the pop up to open.

Is there a function to click anywhere on the window, that would trigger the popup script?

This is the pop up script that's running on the page:
`<script data-cfasync="false" src="//acacdn.com/script/suv4.js" data-adel="lwsu" cdnd="acacdn.com" zid="323555"></script>`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).